# What is the maximum size of 2 dimensional array that we can use in c++ programming?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, c++14, dynamic-programming

I tried using 10^6 by 10^6 array ,it is giving me segmentation fault

Comment: Depends on where you put the array. If that place has enough memory it should be fine, otherwise it will not be.

Comment: Well. even if each element was only one byte, the overall array's size was 10¹². Did you try to run it on a machine with at least 1000GB RAM?

Comment: The maximum size does not depend on the programming language, but on the machine, its current load, etc.: the execution context.

Answer (score 9):

If the array is declared using automatic storage duration, then the size limit is remarkably small, at around 1Mb.

If you're using dynamic storage duration (using `new` and `new[]`), then then limit is much higher.

But either will be insufficient for your gigantic array (at the time of my writing)! You might be able to instantiate a *sparse matrix* of this rank though - see the BLAS library in the Boost distribution.

Answer (score 3):

You need a machine with at least four terabytes of RAM. Do you have such an expensive computer (perhaps costing a million euros, or at least several dozens of thousands of euros).

Since 10<sup>12</sup> numbers of four bytes (e.g. `int`-s) each needs 4 terabytes. Adding all of them might take one or several hours (since a typical operation takes a nanosecond).

If you have an ordinary laptop with 16 Gbytes, you can at most have about a square matrix of about 40000 * 40000 elements, e.g. 1600 million elements (each taking perhaps four or eight bytes; since `sizeof(long)` and `sizeof(double)` are 8 bytes on my Linux x86-64 desktop).

If most elements of your matrix are zero, it is called a [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) and you'll use different [data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) to represent it. There are many resources (books, software libraries, mathematical theories, programming techniques, [numerical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) issues) related to them, and you could dedicate your professional life to sparse matrices.

Read also about [hash-tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), [databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database), [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science))...

Answer (score 1):

It simply depends on your computer's memory size and how much memory your O/S is allocating to your process. You can request your o/s how much memory your process need at the time of you are (executing) submitting the process to your O/S.